# Android NFC intercomunication

Tags: android, nfc

I was looking into making an app for Android based on contact exchange utilizing NFC technology. After reading up on it I ended up with mixed signals on it's feasibility, I seem to have understood that, based on the manufacturer, the NFC technology was wrapped in a proprietary format and consequently impossible to make NFC "tap" apps that worked universally on all Android phones. Is this correct?

If it isn't I am also confused on what happens when phone A that has the app tries to "tap" send a contact to phone that doesn't have the app. What is to be expected to happen? Is it possible to create a separate interaction for exchanges where the receiving phone doesn't have the app? Like for example a message is displayed inviting the user to install the app and the contact gets simply inserted into the user's address book after asking for permission?

Comment: Both users need to have the app, or if you are using a common standard just an app which unterstands the data you are sending. You cannot prompt the other user to install your app.

Comment: Also I am pretty sure that exchanging contacts with nfc already works on all Android phones without any app. Open a contact on your smartphone and then hold another phone to it. You should be given the option to share the contact with the other phone.

Answer (score -1):

When I use NFC features in my apps, I take your solution, which is to invite the user to download and install the app if needed. You only have to send a link to the Play Store profile of your app.

Add this to your *AndroidManifest.xml* to be sure that only users with **NFC support** can see and download your app :

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc" android:required="true" />
```

Comment: Is it possible to also do other actions like adding a contact or is it strictly messages? Also, do you have any resources in mind to learn how to do nfc intercommunication? All I've found so far seems to concentrate on nfc tag reading.

Comment: Look at Beaming NDEF Messages to Other Devices : https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc.html

Comment: Or this link : https://developer.android.com/training/beam-files/index.html?hl=zh-cn

Comment: You can only send messages. As an example, the Contact App receives the message ("hey, you ! I want to share datas with you !") with a receiver and then proceeds to share the contact informations (getting from database, send informations throught NFC messages, adding in database). Just like a client/server operation, any instructions are executed from either client or server side, but only messages are sent in the communication process.